# Comet chat integration with Code Igniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am using comet chat with Code Igniter 2.0.

Problem-

i have a listing page where all the users are listed and i need to show their comet chat status ("Online" or "Offline") next to their name.

For this purpose we have a DB field ('chat_status') in our users table, we usually set this field to '0' or '1' when user logged in we set this field to '1' and when user logged out we set this field to '0'. I just want to use comet chat call backs that will return all the online user_ids in array so i will change their 'chat_status' to '1' in our users table.

I couldn't find any comet chat function or query that will return all the online users in one shot.

Can you please assist me to solve this stuff.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

There is a function in **integration** file [in my case its in its **integration.php**]

`function getFriendsList()` show all the friends on-line but if you want to show all the user insted of friends fellow the instruction given in [link](http://www.cometchat.com/documentation/installing-cometchat/custom-coded-site/php-site)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to edit the 3 sql queries in integration.php function by making changes to the username field .

You can write a subquery and get the status of the user that will be very easy .